# HTML anchor link going to the same page with different query string

Tags: html, query-string

Within a web document (`http://example.com/bla.php?x=123&y=321`), is it possible to create an anchor link which goes to `http://example.com/bla.php?z=111` without putting `bla.php` in the anchor's `href`?

Comment: I believe that `#?z=111` would work

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0  Just tested it, and I believe you are right!  Funny, I've been doing this for a while, and I never knew this part.  Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a href="?z=111">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Steven,  How cross browser supported is doing so?

Comment: @user1032531, sorry not understanding your question, do you mean whether this is working across different browsers?

Comment: Yes,  I tested with current Chrome.  Will it also work with IE5 (not that I need to support, but just asking).  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531, tested on current FF, Chrome, IE 9

Comment: I make use of this in a rails app we have, but it stopped working when we ported it to an Ember SPA with the rails backend just for API. Apparently there's something about SPAs that make this not work.

Comment: Do you know how to preserve the existing query string with this method? So if I'm on a page with `?name=shawn` and I use `?setting=value`, I lose the `name` parameter. Any way around this?